# How to fill a box after being created by node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, fill

I created a `testbox` by using `node` in tikz as follows:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw, regular polygon, regular polygon sides = 6] (testbox) {};
  % \fill [red] (testbox.south east) rectangle (testbox.north west);
  % Thanks @Symbol1 for providing this method, but I didn't make my question clear.
  % Actually I want to fill a 6-side regular polygon
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there any method to fill the `testbox` (which is actually a regular polygon with 6 sides) with color if I **have to `node` first for some reasons** (I know I can use `\node[fill = red]`)?

Comment: `(testbox)` in the fill statement is interpreted as `(testbox.center)`, a coordinate, so there is nothing wrong about it except that it fails to meet your expectation. You can say `\fill [red] (testbox.south east) rectangle (testbox.north west);` but then a red rectangle will cover the text. Use `pgfonlayer` to fix it.

Comment: @Symbol1 Thanks so much, but I notice that your method didn't work for my real question(that was my mistake, I thought they were the same but that was not the case.) -- I want to fill a regular polygon with 6 sides. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 5):

You can save the node path for later use.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw, regular polygon, regular polygon sides = 6,
        save path=\bestpath] (best) {bestagon};
    \scoped[on background layer]% this line not needed if no text to show
    \fill[red, use path=\bestpath];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: red hexagon with text "bestagon"]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw, regular polygon, regular polygon sides = 6] (testbox) {};
  \path[fill=red,draw]  (testbox.corner 1)
  foreach \cornernum in {2,...,6} {-- (testbox.corner \cornernum)} -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works.